# How can I make my javascript array sorted code more optimize and concise?

Tags: arrays, sorting

I am sorting a problem related to array sort and my code works fine. I am practicing on an online coding platform and showed me an error...

34 /35
Time Limit Exceeded

Your program took more time than expected Time Limit: 2.57sec
Hint: Please optimize your code and submit it again

```
class Solution {
    
    sort012(arr, N)
    {
        return arr.sort((a,b)=> a>b ? 1 : -1)

        
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I can write in better way. Please give me an idea and every help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to sort? Just numbers or strings?

Comment: I have an array which hold numbers